# Stripping paint off fiberglass?

Tags: paint-removal, fiberglass

I'd recently acquired a fibreglass recurve bow, with a horrid (in contrast, at least!) pink identification on the handle in what I presume is paint:

[image: bow]

I swapped it in isopropyl alcohol for a bit, nothing. Sat it dabbed in acetone for some time (although the quality of said acetone might have degraded over time) - however it is as remains in the shot below above.

Any idea of what I should do? Is that grey even paint, and is sitting the whole thing in some sorta solvent a bad idea?

Comment: What about methyl ethyl ketone? Not sure if it will damage the fiberglass but it bubbles paint quite well.

Comment: Probably won't. Fiberglass is embedded in epoxy or polyurethane, and once cured, that stuff tends to be very chemically non-reactive (even to its own solvents).